# How to access twig parent for loop inside secondary for

Tags: twig

I have a basic Silex app running Twig templating, I am trying to display some input fields based on a payment type selected, then in a secondary loop, pre-populating the value based, however I am struggling to reference the inital for loop with the key value from the second loop.

```
{% for payment in  app.paymentTypes %}
{% if payment.name == page.affiliate.payment.PaymentType %}
    {% for key, value in payment.fields %}
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="{{ key }}" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{ value }}</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" id="{{ key }}" class="form-control" value=" {{  page.affiliate.payment.key }} ">
                  </div>
              </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The challenge is the: {{  page.affiliate.payment.key }}

The error:

> Twig_Error_Runtime in Template.php line 501:
>   Key "key" for array with keys "PaymentType, ukbank_bank_name, ukbank_swift, ukbank_account_name, ukbank_account_number" does not exist in "settings/payment.html.twig" at line 61
>   in Template.php line 501
>   at Twig_Template->getAttribute(array('PaymentType' => 'UK Bank Transfer', 'ukbank_bank_name' => 'BANK', 'ukbank_swift' => '000000', 'ukbank_account_name' => 'Something Ltd', 'ukbank_account_number' => '00000000'), 'key', array()) in Environment.php(404) : eval()'d code line 145

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'key'` does not exit as key in the `page.affiliate.payment` array.

I guess you want to use the value of `key` in the `page.affiliate.payment` array like this:

```
{{ page.affiliate.payment[key] }}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I was sure I already tried that, thank you for your help!